# How to use Distinct in magento1?

Tags: magento-1, query

I want to use distinct in magento.

```
SELECT DISTINCT level FROM `student`
```

I am trying this code

```
 $collection = Mage::getModel('school/student')->getCollection()
      ->distinct(true)
      ->addAttributeToSelect('level');
```

But its not working.

So how to use distinct in magento

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use group by instead of distinct.

Add  `$collection->getSelect()->group('level')`.

Use group by instead of   `->distinct(true)`.

**Code:**

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('school/student')->getCollection()
          ->addFieldToSelect('level');

$collection->getSelect()->group('level')
```

**Or use:**

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('school/student')->getCollection()->getSelect()
      ->columns('level')
      ->group('level');
```

Comment: addAttributeToSelect is not working

Comment: as it non eav collection so  addAttributeToSelect not work ,use addFieldToSelect

Comment: I m not getting value of level field

Comment: please show table structure of this  model

Comment: Its not working bcz of my silly mistake.Its working now

Answer (score 3):

Tested on Magento ver 1.9.4.3.

```php
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
    ->addFieldToSelect('customer_id')
    ->distinct(true)
    ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['gteq' => 200737]);
```

The resulting MySQL statement is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `main_table`.`customer_id` 
FROM `sales_flat_order` AS `main_table` 
WHERE (main_table.entity_id >= 200737)
```

To return a one-dimension array of `customer_id`, do:

```php
$result = $collection->getColumnValues('customer_id');
```